# CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR seems to be empty. What's the best strategy for OS agnostic way to set this?

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to set a bunch of CXX flags based on processor type.

```
IF(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR} STREQUAL "x86_64")
    SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DAMD64")
ELSE()
    STRING(FIND ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR} "86" 86_res)
    IF(${86_res} EQUAL -1)
        SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DIA32")
    ENDIF()
    STRING(FIND ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR} "arm" arm_res)
    IF(${arm_res} EQUAL -1)
        SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DARM")
    ENDIF()
ENDIF()
```

But for whatever reason CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR is empty and can't run the STREQUAL comparison. Why is this empty?

For now I set this by running

```
EXEC_PROGRAM(uname ARGS -p OUTPUT_VARIABLE CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR)
```

But that won't work on Windows so I'm not sure what I should do here.

Comment: What system are you getting the empty variable on? For some details on the variables behavior see e.g. [here](https://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=9065): "CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR: The name of the CPU CMake is building for. On systems that support uname, this variable is set to the output of uname -p, on windows it is set to the value of the environment variable PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE."

Comment: Forgot to mention that those values are only set after the `project()` call.

Comment: `Linux <name snipped> 4.4.0-112-generic #135-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 19 11:48:36 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`


The project() call makes it a bit tricky. I have the OS related stuff set in a separate cmake file that I include in my CMakeLists.txt file. Putting the project before the include gives me an infinite loop of 

`You have changed variables that require your cache to be deleted.
Configure will be re-run and you may have to reset some variables.`

Comment: Can you please add the content of the file preparing your system? Just a guess, but did you know that most of those variables have an `..._INIT` counterpart? And I admit that the only variables I know the above warning would give is to set the compiler paths or the generator itself (both which should not be part of your `CMakeLists.txt`).

Answer (score 5):

The macro must be used **AFTER** setting the project name with **PROJECT(...)**.

```
MESSAGE("CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR: ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}") # EMPTY!
PROJECT(dummy)
MESSAGE("CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR: ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}") # OK!
```

Output:

```
1> CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR:
1>-- Selecting Windows SDK version...
1> CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR: AMD64
```

It could be assigned by [toolchains](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cross-compiling) when enabling cross-compiling.

Comment: Thanks this exactly my problem :)